# mysql database url, username and password in file

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

how can I place my mysql database url, username and password in a file and how can I access them to use in my java code instead of hard coding them. I've tried google but am not getting clear direction

Comment: You mean to create some kind of configuration file for your Java application?

Comment: Yes. That is what best suites this connection otherwise of now I only can run my application after specifying them in the code which would be better done in a file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a [properties file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html). You can load it by [the `Properties` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).

E.g. `config.properties`:

```xml
url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname
username = foo
password = bar
```

Then you can load and read it as follows (after you've placed it in the classpath):

```
Properties config = new Properties();
config.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));

String url = config.getProperty("url");
String username = config.getProperty("username");
String password = config.getProperty("password");
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the code @BalusC. Let me give it a try. I only don't know how to get started creating the properties file

Comment: It's just a text file. Use any text editor you want. E.g. notepad.

Comment: Thank you. I created the properties file, got a few problems specifying the path to it but got it done eventually

Comment: You're welcome. The example in the answer assumes that you've dropped it just straight in the root of the classpath (or at least added its path to the classpath).

Answer (score 0):

```
 /**
 * Function that connects to a DB and data fro connection is loaded from a    properties file
 * @param fileName
 * @return the connection to DB or null if any problem
 */
public java.sql.Connection connect_to_database_from_properties(String fileName)
{
    Properties prop = new Properties();

    InputStream is;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(fileName);

    prop.load(is);
    String url=prop.getProperty("url");
    String un=prop.getProperty("username");
    String pass=prop.getProperty("password");
    System.out.println("URL: "+url+"  UN:  "+un+"  PASS:  "+pass);
    is.close();
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 

    java.sql.Connection conection =DriverManager.getConnection(url, un, pass);
    return conection;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```